# Build Failed in ionic 2 for IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, npm-install

Running `ionic cordova build ios` will result in the following error:

```
Preparing Firebase on iOS
IOS project Code Sign Entitlements now set to: LifeBuddy/Resources/LifeBuddy.entitlements
Entitlements file is in reference section.
Error: ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.2 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm install -g ios-deploy'

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

When running the suggested command `npm install -g ios-deploy` I receive this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
        Write auxiliary files
(2 failures)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 65
npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.9.3 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 65
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.9.3 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dev-13/.npm/_logs/2018-07-31T08_07_03_860Z-debug.log
```

Comment: On which machine you are building your app ? Mac or Windows ?

Comment: @CodeChanger on Mac machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true

Comment: i am getting this 
Error = 

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/PATH/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,PROJECTNAME.xcworkspace,-scheme,PROJECTNAME,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,PROJECTNAME.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/PATH/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/PATH

Comment: Do you have a development provisioning profile on your build machine.  Does the project run on the simulator.